# How do I register for notification of new subscribers via webhook?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am looking to build an ExactTarget Marketing Cloud app.  I need to know whenever a new subscriber is added or removed.  Is there a way to register for a webhook that can do this?

EDIT to add my use case: I am looking to perform a two-way synchronization to track the subscriber lists on a separate platform that can also handle subscribe/unsubscribes.  I think I can make do with a webhook just on that side, and polling against ExactTarget, but wanted to make sure it did not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't a webhook available that can do that. You can only perform CRUD operations on subscribers. Can you provide more details regarding your use case, then perhaps I can suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: added use case in question. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it would be helpful to understand a little more about your use case. Are you building a custom subscription center? If so, it's not ideal to maintain subscriber records in two separate databases (Marketing Cloud and externally). You could 'synchronise' data by retrieving all records in individual subscriber lists and updating them but this is somewhat awkward and would require some heavy payloads if you have many subscribers.

My suggestion would be to manage subscriber lists in Marketing Cloud. I've built a custom subscription center for a client where the page is hosted externally and uses the Fuel SOAP API to:

1. Retrieve all available public subscription lists
2. Retrieve subscription lists for a specific subscriber
3. Update subscription preferences for a subscriber

We include a link to the custom subscription center on emails, for example https://domain.com/subscriptions/%%Primary_Key%% — note that you will need to request the subscription centre 'requirement' to be disabled from your Marketing Cloud account so you can use a custom subscription center.

Here are the API methods that you would need to use.

### Retrieve available lists

Use the following SOAP request with the **Retrieve** SOAP Action to retrieve all available lists based on a list type (in this case, we are filtering public lists):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">passowrd</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>List</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ListName</Properties>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>List.Type</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>Public</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This request will return all public lists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:0e31d32e-f996-4baa-aa41-b5bb739e495a</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:bd6a2d16-3e7a-45b3-9ebd-d79c637f5211</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-b7542428-99f4-48b3-8336-013ab3fc2fa4">
                <wsu:Created>2015-01-20T12:20:32Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-01-20T12:25:32Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>ae2adcbf-9098-44f9-a8d4-0462ab15acb8</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="List">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ID>13638</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <ListName>Updates and alerts (1410)</ListName>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="List">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ID>14436</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <ListName>Special offers from trusted partners (1114)</ListName>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### Check subscriber status for lists

Use the following method to check subscriber status for a given `SubscriberKey` using the **Retrieve** SOAP Action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ListID</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>999999</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This request will return the status for each list that the user is subscribed to using the **Retrieve** SOAP Action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:9b82e891-a839-427c-b10c-1bd07cc4bab2</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:5da32f99-eb49-4287-91aa-fdaa7fbc36f9</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-40c27a93-d8f7-45d7-9c73-2bf2ca15a8c9">
                <wsu:Created>2015-02-02T06:01:04Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-02-02T06:06:04Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>da8bbe32-d840-4ef6-9153-309b2f1cb18b</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <ListID>372</ListID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Status>Unsubscribed</Status>
                <ListID>13638</ListID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <ListID>14436</ListID>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### Update list preferences for a subscriber

You can then display the lists on your custom subscription page and provide form controls for subscribers to update their preferences for each list. To update preferences, make the following request using the **Update** SOAP Action, where the value for `Status` is either `Active` (to subscribe) or `Unsubscribed` (to unsubscribe)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
             <SubscriberKey>999999</SubscriberKey> 
             <Lists>
                <ID>14436</ID>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <Action>Update</Action>
             </Lists>
             <Lists>
                <ID>13638</ID>
                <Status>Unsubscribed</Status>
                <Action>Update</Action>
             </Lists>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This request should return the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>UpdateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:cb61f903-bde4-407c-a3bf-50c98da7fb88</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:c99e4a01-3f1b-4745-8ca9-cb26965c5649</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-fdd32562-afa9-452c-b855-6ebc5c8cdcfa">
                <wsu:Created>2015-01-20T12:50:39Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-01-20T12:55:39Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <UpdateResponse
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Results>
                <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
                <StatusMessage>Updated Subscriber.</StatusMessage>
                <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
                <Object xsi:type="Subscriber">
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ID>98710956</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <SubscriberKey>999999</SubscriberKey>
                    <Lists>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                        <ID>14436</ID>
                        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                        <Status>Active</Status>
                        <Action>Update</Action>
                    </Lists>
                    <Lists>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                        <ID>13638</ID>
                        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                        <Status>Unsubscribed</Status>
                        <Action>Update</Action>
                    </Lists>
                </Object>
            </Results>
            <RequestID>851ef505-35a7-453b-b566-d4b7b072053e</RequestID>
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
        </UpdateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If this isn't what you are looking for then please let me know and I'll see if I can assist further.